# How do you change the state of the window close button in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In Cocoa Applications, you often see a little red dot in the window's close button when you have unsaved data; TextEdit is a good example of this. I've pored through the Cocoa documentation but I can't find a way to programmatically set this state. I'm sure there's some really easy way to do it, but obviously I'm missing something.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To set it programmatically, you can use the `-setDocumentEdited:` method of NSWindow.  If you are writing a Document-based app, NSDocumentManager should automatically detect when there are unsaved changes to the NSUndoManager associated with the current NSDocument.

Answer (score 14):

Depends on what kind of application you're building. If it's `NSDocument` based, use `NSDocument`'s `updateChangeCount:` method. If you've just got an `NSWindowController`, use `setDocumentEdited:`. `NSWindow` has a `setDocumentEdited:` method if all you've got is the `NSWindow`.

Comment: And of course you can test the state when it's time to close or whenever: in your window controller `if self.window!.isDocumentEdited {...`.  Saves defining you own variable.

Answer (score 9):

Also, in 10.6, the 'setDocumentEdited' marks the application as dirty, and so can't be fast-killed. If you don't call this, and set the flag in the Info.plist (see [What's New in 10.6](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008898-SW22))

```
<key>NSSupportsSuddenTermination</key>
<string>YES</string>
```

That way, if your app is running (but isn't dirty) then Mac OS X can simply kill it, rather than invoking polite shutdown requests. If your document(s) are marked dirty (or the window is) then it'll go through the normal app shutdown process to shut it down.